# Isomorphism of space whose dual are isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

If dual of two normed linear space $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic, then does this implies that these two spaces are also isomorphic?

I encountered this problem while proving that if dual of $X$ is reflexive then it implies that $X$ is also reflexive.

Dual of $X$: All bounded linear functional on $X$

$X$ is reflexive: Dual of Dual of $X$ is isomorphic to $X$, if the natural mapping from $X$ to Dual of Dual of $X$ is onto.

Comment: Are these *normed* spaces, and do you mean the *topological dual*? If yes, one can define a normed space whose topological dual is $0$, so the answer is no in this case.

Comment: @Berci No, the topological dual of a normed space is never trivial (unless the space itself is). That's a basic consequence of Hahn-Banach. However, I agree that this question is lacking details.

Comment: Ah yes, indeed. I wanted to mean *topological vector spaces*.

Comment: @Berci I have added some details to make it clear.

Comment: As linked, this question has been asked (answered before). Just one remark: The definition of reflexive Banach spaces is subtly different from what you state. A space can be isometrically isomorphic to its second dual and still not be reflexive.